# Passenger crashing on startup

Tags: passenger, redmine

I'm a bit of a newbie to this. I'm just updating redmine/ruby(2.4.0)/passenger/apache2.4 on SLES linux and it seems like passenger (5.3.4) is crashing on start up. Can anyone understand what is going on in this crash dump file? Here is a sample of the dump file. 
Passenger-config validate install checks all came back as  'Everything looks good'

```
    [ pid=20304, timestamp=1534916330 ] Process aborted! signo=SIGSEGV(11), reason=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=0x0, randomSeed=1534916327
[ pid=20304 ] Crash log dumped to /var/tmp/passenger-crash-log.1534916330
[ pid=20304 ] Date, uname and ulimits:
Wed Aug 22 15:08:50 ACST 2018
Linux 3.0.101-0.47.71-default #1 SMP Thu Nov 12 12:22:22 UTC 2015 (b5b212e) x86_64 x86_64
core file size          (blocks, -c) 1
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63924
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 6964728
open files                      (-n) 100000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63924
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 13263520
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
[ pid=20304 ] Phusion Passenger version: 5.3.4
[ pid=20304 ] libc backtrace available!
--------------------------------------
[ pid=20304 ] Backtrace with 34 frames:
ERROR: cannot execute '/home/redmine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/wrappers/ruby "/home/redmine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.3.4/src/helper-scripts/backtrace-sanitizer.rb"' for sanitizing the backtrace, writing to stderr directly...
Passenger core[0x5f61b0]
Passenger core[0x5f69e4]
Passenger core[0x5f72ab]
Passenger core[0x5f7cf1]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf850)[0x7faa292ca850]
/var/appdevelop/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1(X509_PUBKEY_get0+0x20)[0x7faa287732e0]
/var/appdevelop/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1(X509_PUBKEY_get+0x6)[0x7faa287733c6]
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8(+0x43550)[0x7faa27641550]
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8(SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file+0x92)[0x7faa276417f2]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x2c7bb)[0x7faa28c597bb]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x2e466)[0x7faa28c5b466]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x310a4)[0x7faa28c5e0a4]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x31312)[0x7faa28c5e312]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x4cb31)[0x7faa28c79b31]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x134be)[0x7faa28c404be]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x27128)[0x7faa28c54128]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x2a1aa)[0x7faa28c571aa]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x2a334)[0x7faa28c57334]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x3c062)[0x7faa28c69062]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(+0x3c2fb)[0x7faa28c692fb]
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4(curl_easy_perform+0x148)[0x7faa28c69f0d]
Passenger core[0x76b5db]
Passenger core[0x79e954]
Passenger core[0x7c577c]
Passenger core[0x6d2b40]
Passenger core[0x6d8b09]
Passenger core[0x6d8b46]
Passenger core[0x6d8b65]
Passenger core[0x5b71ab]
Passenger core[0x8f3733]
Passenger core[0x59a354]
Passenger core[0x8e6291]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7806)[0x7faa292c2806]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7faa27b669bd]
--------------------------------------
[ pid=20304 ] Dumping additional diagnostical information...
--------------------------------------
### Backtraces
Thread 'Main thread' (0x7faa298b8760, LWP 20304):
     in 'void waitForExitEvent()' (CoreMain.cpp:1085)
     in 'void mainLoop()' (CoreMain.cpp:973)
     in 'int runCore()' (CoreMain.cpp:1216)

Thread 'Pool analytics collector' (0x7faa298b5700, LWP 20304):
     in 'static void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Pool::collectAnalytics(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::PoolPtr)' (AnalyticsCollection.cpp:52)
```

Comment: Do you have passenger installed by system, as well?

Comment: I don't think so.
We are getting this error in the system logs when trying to start it.
messages:Aug 30 15:06:27 servername kernel: [ 2925.632236] PassengerAgent[16070]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000005f6492 sp 00007f185b2ab8b0 error 4 in PassengerAgent[400000+6b1000]